# Create a MAPI provider

Tags: .net, email, mapi

The accounting department of my company uses software that can send the customer statements via email.
The problem is that this software uses Outlook via MAPI to send all documents in pdf format.
It is necessary that accountants click the "Send" button for each message.
With several hundred customers is quite long.

So I try to create a small application would be registered as the default mail application.
It intercepts the messages and attachments through MAPI, and send them directly via SMTP.

Is it possible ? If this is the case, how to use MAPI to do this in .Net?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot create MAPI providers in .Net. Even directly **using** Extended MAPI is not supported.

Secondly, wouldn't the user still need to click Send on each message? What are you trying to do? Mail several recipients at a time? You can easily do that using the Outlook Object Model.

Comment: The accounting software sends messages one by one and starts the following message when Outlook places the previous in the outbox.

The goal is that the messages are sent to their destination without user action.

Since the accounting software uses MAPI, if I want to make life easier for accountants, I do not have a choice.

Which languages can do what I want?

Comment: What is "the following message"? Do you mean the security prompt?

Comment: The messages came one at a time so I mean _message n_ and _message n+1_.

Comment: "Message" as in "an Outlook inspector displaying the message where the user must click the Send button"? In that case there is nothing you can do - that application displays a message, there is no way for you to change that behavior.

Comment: I want to replace Outlook as the default mailing application by an homemade app to intercept the email messages and send them silently.

Comment: If the other app uses the Outlook Object Model, how can you replace it without recreating all of its functionality? You can use OOM and the Application.Inspectors.Add event - it will fire when a new inspector is opened. You can then retreiev MailItem from Inspector.CurrentItem and call MailItem.Send.